# XIB outlets unit testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xib, ocunit

I have following code to test if view is properly configured(among others, I have the `monthScrollview` placed as a subview of view:

```
@implementation ECBrowserViewControllerTests
-(void)setUp
{
  //-deviceSpecific simply adds suffix like '_iPad'
  main=[[ECBrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[@"ECBrowserViewController" deviceSpecific] bundle:nil];
}
-(void)testOutlets
{
    STAssertNotNil(main.view, @"View outlet not set!");

    STAssertNotNil(main.monthScrollView, @"no month scrollview");
    STAssertTrue(main.monthScrollView.pagingEnabled, @"Paging should be enabled");
}

-(void)testPaging
{
    STAssertNotNil(main.monthScrollView, @"no month scrollview");
    STAssertTrue(main.monthScrollView.pagingEnabled, @"Paging should be enabled");
}
@end
```

Could any one tell me why the `testPaging` fails, while `testOutlets` succeeds? I figured out that's about checking the parentView first, but why?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and builtin SenTestingKit

Comment: At the risk of asking a stupid question, `monthScrollView` is connected to its outlet, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is. `testOutlets` passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply fails because ViewController's views in COCOA are *loaded lazily*:
The *view* property is not set until it's needed, namely when one tries to fetch its value for the first time. At that moment `loadView` is summoned.

The reason why your testPaging test fails is due to the fact that the viewController's view in never fetched.

So, in your specific test, you have to explicitly invoke `-view` over a the view controller in order to have its `-loadView` method/callback summoned and hence get its view (and subviews) allocated.

Comment: Awesome answer! Do you have a reference that says the views are loaded lazily?

Comment: Thank you, I remember reading it either on Apple's documentation about view controllers or on some books (Unfortunately I can't remember which one). Anyway it's quite easy to prove view controller's views lazy loading by writing some code and running some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)testPaging
{
    [main view];    // Force nib to load

    STAssertNotNil(main.monthScrollView, @"no month scrollview");
    STAssertTrue(main.monthScrollView.pagingEnabled, @"Paging should be enabled");
}
```